# How can I annotate text in Basemap using the exact coordinates of the location in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, geospatial, matplotlib-basemap

I have created a Basemap of Asia using following lines of code. The projection used is "marcator". The region I want to show in this basemap is Chitwan, Nepal. The coordinates is also provided.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

chitwan = (27.618556599999998, 84.45385600798173)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.5, 2, 2])  #left, bottom, width, height

m = Basemap(
    llcrnrlon = 30,
    llcrnrlat = 0,
    urcrnrlon = 120,
    urcrnrlat = 60,
    projection = "merc",
    resolution = "l"
           )

m.plot(chitwan[1], chitwan[0],
      latlon = True,
      marker = "s",
      color = "blue",
      markersize = 20)

m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()

plt.annotate(text = "Chitwan, Nepal", xy = chitwan)

plt.show()
```

I am able to add a blue square marker in Chitwan, Nepal using

```
m.plot(chitwan[1], chitwan[0],
      latlon = True,
      marker = "s",
      color = "blue",
      markersize = 40)
```

Passing `latlon = True` allows me to draw the marker using the coordinates of the place directly.

However, I also want to annotate "Chitwan, Nepal" as a text in the same location.
I tried `plt.annotate(text = "Chitwan, Nepal", xy = chitwan)`. However, this plots the text on the lower left corner of the Basemap as shown below.

[image]

I think this should be because the latitude and longitude coordinates of the text is not projected to that of the Basemap. So how can I project the coordinates of my location such that the text is also inserted in the same location as the marker? Is it possible to do this by passing the exact coordinates of the place directly and passing an argument similar to `latlon = True` for the marker?

Comment: The text is plotted way outside of the map with the code you suggested.

Comment: I tried using fig, ax = plt.subplots() and the text is still outside of the map.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I figured out the way for this myself.

I need to use:

```
x, y = m(chitwan[1], chitwan[0])
```

The x and y are projected to the map location with longitude and latitude of chitwan respectively.

And then I annotated the text as follows:

```
ax.annotate(text = "Chitwan, Nepal",
           xy = (x+5,y+5),
           )
```

I get the resulting plot as shown:
[image: Image after solution]